# ¿Cómo puedo buscar preguntas que yo mismo haya formulado?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Esa es la cuestión. Intento buscar preguntas que ya he formulado y han sido correctamente respondidas, porque, desafortunadamente, se me ha estropeado el fichero donde las tenía con sus respuestas.

No veo ningún enlace del tipo "Mis preguntas" o similar.

Podéis indicarme cómo localizarlas?

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ingresa a tu perfil, arriba a la derecha en tu imagen de perfil, tab actividad > tab preguntas

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/40273/jose-quijado?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera más rápida es escribir `user:me is:question` en el buscador